# Nginx:Multiple Url redirection

Tags: regex, nginx

I am new to Nginx..and need to setup some redirects

We are launching our latest code, and what to redirect all instance of the sites

for eg:-

```
https://woi.com/movies
https://woi.com/movies/Fear
https://woi.com/videos
https://woi.com/videos/Captain
```

to

```
https://woi.tv/#!/movies
https://woi.tv/#!/movies/Fear
https://woi.tv/#!/videos
https://woi.tv/#!/videos/Captain
```

I have made changes in Nginx.conf file:-

```
Http
{
...
location /movies {
    rewrite ^.* https://$woi.tv/movies permanent;
    }

    location /movies/ {
    rewrite ^.* https://$woi.tv/movies/ permanent;
   }

location /videos {
    rewrite ^.* https://$woi.tv/videos permanent;
    }

    location /videos/ {
    rewrite ^.* https://$woi.tv/videos/ permanent;
   }
}
```

I dont know if I am right. But the above is not working.

Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect all unconditionally you can try something like this, not sure if the `#` can be written in a redirect or not, but you can try.

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name example.com;
  root /path/to/root;
  index index.php; # or whatever index
  # ssl settings
  location = / {
    # the non redirecting settings
    try_files $uri $uri/;
  }
  location / {
    # the remaining of the site, we should redirect here
    return 301 $scheme://$http_host#!$request_uri;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

On a second thought I think this would break the assets, so I think the redirect should be as a fall back

```
location / {
  try_files $uri @redirect;
}
location @redirect {
  return 301 $scheme://$http_host#!$request_uri;
}
```